# PersistenceException -Duplicate annotation of name in Simple XML deserialization

Tags: android, simple-framework

I test simple xml tutorial from this [link](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/examples/example7/example7.zip). I change the xml file like this.

```
<example xmlns:ns1="http://www.blah.com/ns/a">
  <a>
    <b>
        <x>abc</x>
      <ns1:x>blah</ns1:x>
    </b>
  </a>
</example>
```

and I add the following coding into the `Example7` class.

```
   @Path("a/b")
   @Element(name = "x")
   private String x_;
```

I got this exception `PersistenceException : Duplicate annotation of name 'x' on field 'x'`. I would like to know how to overcome this exception.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post at least the other `x` variable of your class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your field `x` within your class `Example7` to use the namespace `ns1`.

```
@Element
@Path("a/b")
@Namespace(reference="http://www.blah.com/ns/a", prefix="ns1")
private String x;
```

Also see the [corresponding section of Simple XML tutorial](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#namesoace).